# Can multiple signed PDF files be merged into one?

Tags: pdf, digital-signature

It seems that the industry converged to the weird consensus where the digital signature of a file is stored in the file itself, on a crude imitation of paper documents. If I have a PDF document that must be signed by a bunch of people, I must sign the file, send the new version to another person, who will sign and create another file, which must be sent to the next person, who will create another file, and so on. This is obviously error prone and impractical, but this is how the only signing tool I have from my government allows me to do (I could also get a smartcard with direct access to the signing keys, but that is expensive and most people don't have it).

I want to do it in parallel: everybody gets the original unsigned PDF, sign it individually, send me the signed PDF, and I combine all the signatures into a single PDF file. Is this a supported workflow? Is there a tool to do that? Even if not supported and there is no tool, is that theoretically possible? Like, is there something in the PDF specification that would invalidate the signature if it is copied to another version of the document with the same contents, but more signatures?

Comment: Docu Sign gets close to what you want

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Pro can do this process automatically for you - [link](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/send-for-signature.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you sign a PDF with existing signatures, you are *also signing those signatures* as part of the document contents. Copying the signatures to another document will indeed invalidate them. This is to ensure that someone doesn't remove/alter a signature after someone signs.

In terms of workflow, signatures stack on top of each other until a final signoff. Multiple "asynchronous" signatures are not supported by PDFs on a single document. If it's required, you would need to treat each signature as a separate document, having everyone sign a separate copy. (I've seen people manage this with PDF "collection" file types like a Portfolio, but it's awkward)

Smarter tools like Adobe Sign/DocuSign/PandaDoc basically handle multiple signatures by storing one "current" copy of the document (usually in the cloud) and only send links to sign *that* document, avoiding the issue of multiple copies floating around.

Comment: So, the further up you are in the list, the more signatures you can remove from the document?

Comment: @lvella Not sure I understand your question correctly, but yes. You can always remove the most recent signature without invalidating the others (basically just an Undo). There is no way for you to re-add a signature after it's been removed, other than signing the document again.